# ExecutorService, standard way to avoid to task queue getting too full

Tags: java, concurrency

I am using `ExecutorService` for ease of concurrent multithreaded program. Take following code:

```
while(xxx) {
    ExecutorService exService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_THREADS);
    ...  
    Future<..> ... = exService.submit(..);
    ...
}
```

In my case the problem is that `submit()` is not blocking if all `NUMBER_THREADS` are occupied. The consequence is that the Task queue is getting flooded by many tasks. The consequence of this is, that shutting down the execution service with `ExecutorService.shutdown()` takes ages (`ExecutorService.isTerminated()` will be false for long time). Reason is that the task queue is still quite full.

For now my workaround is to work with semaphores to disallow to have to many entries inside the task queue of `ExecutorService`:

```
...
Semaphore semaphore=new Semaphore(NUMBER_THREADS);

while(xxx) {
    ExecutorService exService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_THREADS); 
    ...
    semaphore.aquire();  
    // internally the task calls a finish callback, which invokes semaphore.release()
    // -> now another task is added to queue
    Future<..> ... = exService.submit(..); 
    ...
}
```

I am sure there is a better more encapsulated solution?

Answer (score 36):

The trick is to use a fixed queue size and:

```
new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy()
```

I also recommend using Guava's [ListeningExecutorService](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained).
Here is an example consumer/producer queues.

```
private ListeningExecutorService producerExecutorService = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(newFixedThreadPoolWithQueueSize(5, 20));
private ListeningExecutorService consumerExecutorService = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(newFixedThreadPoolWithQueueSize(5, 20));

private static ExecutorService newFixedThreadPoolWithQueueSize(int nThreads, int queueSize) {
    return new ThreadPoolExecutor(nThreads, nThreads,
                                  5000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                                  new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(queueSize, true), new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
}
```

Anything better and you might want to consider a MQ like RabbitMQ or ActiveMQ as they have QoS technology.

Comment: Great answer, with full example.

Answer (score 6):

You can call `ThreadPoolExecutor.getQueue().size()` to find out the size of the waiting queue. You can take an action if the queue is too long.  I suggest running the task in the current thread if the queue is too long to slow down the producer (if that is appropriate).

Answer (score 6):

A true blocking ThreadPoolExecutor has been on the wishlist of many, there's even a JDC bug opened on it.
I'm facing the same problem, and came across this:
http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/10/23/creating-a-notifying-blocking-thread-pool-executor.html

It's an implementation of a BlockingThreadPoolExecutor, implemented using a RejectionPolicy that uses offer to add the task to the queue, waiting for the queue to have room. It looks good.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4522411/394431) to another question suggests using a custom `BlockingQueue` subclass which blocks on `offer()` by delegating to `put()`.  I think that ends up working more or less the same as this `RejectedExecutionHandler`.

Answer (score 4):

You're better off creating the [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) yourself (which is what Executors.newXXX() does anyway).

In the constructor, you can pass in a BlockingQueue for the Executor to use as its task queue.  If you pass in a size constrained BlockingQueue (like [LinkedBlockingQueue](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html)), it should achieve the effect you want.

```
ExecutorService exService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(NUMBER_THREADS, NUMBER_THREADS, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(workQueueSize));
```

Comment: i see. i overlooked a detail at http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29. there it is mentioned, that as standard an unbounded queue is used.

Comment: i tried it out. unfortunately your solution does not block (as I want) but throws a RejectedExecutionException. also found: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t389526-threadpoolexecutor-with-blocking-execute.html. the presented workarounds seem to be more complicated as my semaphore example, damn!

Comment: this dont working because of RejectedExecutionException if queue is full

Comment: Downvoted because it does not address the point in the question.

Comment: Downvoted too, it doesnt block but throw a rejected

Answer (score 2):

you can add another bloquing queue that's has limited size to controle the size of internal queue in executorService, some thinks like semaphore but very easy.
before executor you put() and whene the task achive take(). take() must be inside the task code

Answer (score 1):

I know this is too old but might be useful for other developers. So submitting one of the [solution](https://github.com/prasadbhalerao1983/custom-thread-pools/blob/master/src/main/java/com/executor/BoundedThreadPoolExecutor.java).

As you asked for better encapsulated solution. It is done by extending ThreadPoolExecutor and overriding submit method.

BoundedThreadpoolExecutor implemented using Semaphore. Java executor service throws RejectedExecutionException when the task queue becomes full. Using unbounded queue may result in out of memory error. This can be avoided by controlling the number of tasks being submitted using executor service. This can be done by using semaphore or by implementing RejectedExecutionHandler.