# Elegantly implementing queue length indicators to ExecutorServices

Tags: java, concurrency, queue, executorservice, executor

Why, oh why doesn't `java.util.concurrent` provide a queue length indicators for  its `ExecutorService`s? Recently I found myself doing something like this:

```
ExecutorService queue = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
AtomicInteger queueLength = new AtomicInteger();
...

public void addTaskToQueue(Runnable runnable) {
    if (queueLength.get() < MAX_QUEUE_LENGTH) {
        queueLength.incrementAndGet(); // Increment queue when submitting task.
        queue.submit(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                runnable.run();
                queueLength.decrementAndGet(); // Decrement queue when task done.
            }
        });
    } else {
        // Trigger error: too long queue
    }
}
```

Which works ok, but... I think this really should be implemented as a part of the `ExecutorService`. It's dumb and error prone to carry around a counter *separated* from the actual queue, whose length the counter is supposed to indicate (reminds me of C arrays). But, `ExecutorService`s are obtained via static factory methods, so there's no way to simply extend the otherwise excellent single thread executor and add a queue counter. So what should I do:

1. Reinvent stuff already implemented in JDK?
2. Other clever solution?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

There is a more direct way:

```
ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor( 1, 1, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>() );
// add jobs
// ...
int size = executor.getQueue().size();
```

This is directly copied from `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor` in JDK 1.6. The `LinkedBlockingQueue` that is passed to the constructor is actually the very object that you will get back from `getQueue`.

Comment: Ha! So you just need to re-implement very tiny part (one line) of the JDK. Quite acceptable :-) Thanks for this.

Comment: Actually I'd go with the cast myself because ThreadPoolExecutor is a public class and thus in some way also part of the public API of newSingleThreadExecutor. I think it is less likely that the object created by newSingleThreadExecutor will not be a ThreadPoolExecutor anymore than that the arguments of the constructor invocation in newSingleThreadExecutor might change some day, i.e. to use some more efficent or more precise implementation or whatever.

Comment: Ironically, on one machine I tried this I got an `FinalizableDelegatedExecutorService` instead of an `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

Comment: Looking at [the source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/Executors.java#Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor%28%29), I don't see how you can cast an `ExecutorService` directly to a `ThreadPoolExecutor`. Also I keep getting a `ClassCastException`, like always.

Answer (score 4):

While you can check the queue size directly. Another way of dealing with a queue that's getting too long is making the internal queue bounded.

```
public static
ExecutorService newFixedThreadPoolWithQueueSize(int nThreads, int queueSize) {
  return new ThreadPoolExecutor(nThreads, nThreads,
                              5000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                              new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(queueSize, true));
}
```

This will cause RejectedExecutionExceptions (see [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit(java.util.concurrent.Callable))) when you exceed the limit.

If you want to avoid the exception the calling thread can be hijacked to execute the function. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247734/executorservice-standard-way-to-avoid-to-task-queue-getting-too-full) for a solution.

#### References

- [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#ThreadPoolExecutor(int,%20int,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit,%20java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue))